# Cannot install Flash Develop because of 64 bits

Tags: windows-7

I have already installed flash develop http://www.flashdevelop.org and I just wanted to reinstall somewhere else.

I downloaded again but when launching it it says cannot install because it requires 64 bits.

I can't find any 64 bits and I wonder why it has installed once and not any more ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked for me. Did you download it from here ( http://www.flashdevelop.org/community/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=6695)? Maybe you have 32 bit Java?

Comment: file was corrupt.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've installed the 64 bit version rather than the 32 bit version. However, I've had a quick look at the downloads section and can't see anything obvious that would indicate that there's more than one version.

Double check the download and the installation instructions. Was there a step that asked you to choose a version to install?

Answer (score 0):

Flash Develop supports both 32 bit and 64 bit OS.